# Inspect a received D-Bus signal on its handler

Tags: python, dbus

I'm building a general-purpose DBus proxy receiver that a user can leverage to configure generic signal listeners and proxy them to another service.

Therefore, I need to be able to listen to *all* the bus signals:

```py
from dbus import SessionBus

def handler(*args, **kwargs):
  print(args, kwargs)

# ...

bus = SessionBus()
bus.add_signal_receiver(handler, signal_name=None, dbus_interface=None, path=None)
```

The problem with this approach is that I have no way from the handler's `args` and `kwargs` to tell which interface/signal name/path are associated with the signal:

```
args=(dbus.String(':1.22395'), dbus.String(''), dbus.String(':1.22395')) kwargs={}
```

Is there an easy way to inspect DBus to get more information about the received signal? I guess that it should exist (`dbus-monitor --monitor` does more or less the same thing that I'm trying to do), but I couldn't find any references online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the `sender_keyword`, `destination_keyword`, etc. keyword arguments of [`add_signal_receiver()`](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/dbus.bus.html#dbus.bus.BusConnection.add_signal_receiver).

You may want to consider using [pydbus, or some other more modern D-Bus binding](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/DBusBindings/#python). dbus-python is old and not very Pythonic. It’s [not very actively maintained](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/news.html), and certainly not actively developed.

Comment: Thanks! `pydbus` doesn't seem that actively maintained either (the latest commit was in 2018), but at least it has a better interface and it passes information about interface, object and signal to the handler - so `SessionBus().subscribe(signal_fired=handler)` suffices to get all the information. Now I just have to migrate all the code I wrote for `dbus` to `pydbus` :)

Comment: Oh dear, I hadn’t realised `pydbus` wasn’t actively maintained any more. Thanks for letting me know. `python-sdbus` might be a better choice then? I’ve never used it, but I know sdbus (the C version) is well designed. YMMV.